# Implementing safe navigation in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Recently I came across the following article in Medium about [Using ES6's Proxy for safe Object property access](https://medium.com/@chekofif/using-es6-s-proxy-for-safe-object-property-access-f42fa4380b2c) from Gidi Meir Morris. I really liked it and wanted to give it a try in my Typescript project for optional nested objects without loosing type checking.

In order to turn optional nested objects into all-required, I'm using the following type:

```
export type DeepRequired<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: DeepRequired<T[P]>;
};
```

Gidi's code in typescript (including some hacks...):

```
export interface Dictionary {
    [key: string]: any;
};

const isObject = (obj: any) => obj && typeof obj === 'object';
const hasKey = (obj: object, key: string) => key in obj;

const Undefined: object = new Proxy({}, {
    get: function (target, name) {
        return Undefined;
    }
});

export const either = (val: any, fallback: any) => (val === Undefined ? fallback : val);

export function safe<T extends Dictionary>(obj: T): DeepRequired<T> {
    return new Proxy(obj, {
    get: function(target, name){
        return hasKey(target, name as string) ? 
        (isObject(target[name]) ? safe(target[name]) : target[name]) : Undefined;
    }
    }) as DeepRequired<T>;
}
```

Usage example:

```
interface A {
    a?: {
        b?: {
            c?: {
                d?: string
            }
        }
    },
    b: boolean,
    c?: {
        d: {
            e: number
        }
    },
    d?: Array<{e: boolean}> 
}
const obj: A = {b: false};
const saferObj = safe(obj);
```

Scenarios that it works without TS errors:

```
test('should work for nested optional objects', () => {
    expect(either(saferObj.a.b.c.d, null)).toEqual(null);
    expect(either(saferObj.a.b.c.d, undefined)).toEqual(undefined);
    expect(either(saferObj.a.b.c.d, 322)).toEqual(322);
});

test('should work for required members', () => {
    expect(either(saferObj.b, null)).toEqual(false);
});

test('should work for mixed optional/required tree', () => {
    expect(either(saferObj.c.d.e, null)).toEqual(null);
});
```

As for arrays...

```
test('should work for arrays', () => {
    expect(either(saferObj.d[0].e, null)).toEqual(null);
});
```

TS compiler throws the following error:

```
[ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'DeepRequired<{ e: boolean; }[]>' has no index signature.
```

Any idea how can i make this work for Arrays?

Comment: What version of Typescript are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work as is on Typescript 2.9 and above because in Typescript 2.9 the `keyof` operator includes numeric and symbol keys as well as string keys which were previously returned by `keyof`. [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20export%20type%20DeepRequired%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D-%3F%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20extends%20Array%3Cinfer%20U%3E%3FArray%3CDeepRequired%3CU%3E%3E%3A%20DeepRequired%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20Dictionary%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20isObject%20%3D%20(obj%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20obj%20%26%26%20typeof%20obj%20%3D%3D%3D%20'object'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20hasKey%20%3D%20(obj%3A%20object%2C%20key%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20key%20in%20obj%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20Undefined%3A%20object%20%3D%20new%20Proxy(%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20get%3A%20function%20(target%2C%20name)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Undefined%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20const%20either%20%3D%20(val%3A%20any%2C%20fallback%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20(val%20%3D%3D%3D%20Undefined%20%3F%20fallback%20%3A%20val)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20safe%3CT%20extends%20Dictionary%3E(obj%3A%20T)%3A%20DeepRequired%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Proxy(obj%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20get%3A%20function(target%2C%20name)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20hasKey(target%2C%20name%20as%20string)%20%3F%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(isObject(target%5Bname%20as%20any%5D)%20%3F%20safe(target%5Bname%20as%20any%5D)%20%3A%20target%5Bname%20as%20any%5D)%20%3A%20Undefined%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%20as%20DeepRequired%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%3F%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b%3F%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c%3F%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20d%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b%3A%20boolean%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c%3F%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20d%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20d%3F%3A%20Array%3C%7Be%3A%20boolean%7D%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20obj%3A%20A%20%3D%20%7Bb%3A%20false%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20saferObj%20%3D%20safe(obj)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20saferObj.d%5B0%5D.e%20%2F%2F%20array%20access%20works%20as%20expected)

If you want to stick to 2.8 for some reasons, you can use the workaround of handling arrays explicitly in `DeepRequired` using a conditional type.

```
export type DeepRequired<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: T[P] extends Array<infer U>?Array<DeepRequired<U>>: DeepRequired<T[P]>;
};
```